# Using .scrollTop animation with mobile device not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, viewport, infinite-scroll

I have a footer that appears when a user scrolls down on the bottom of the page, but for seem reason it doesn't appear to be working on mobile devices, particularly the ipad, and it seems finicky on there. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't and only when using the ipad vertically.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $window = jQuery(window);
var   $document = jQuery(document);
var  footer = jQuery('.footer');

footer.css({opacity: 0});

$window.on('scroll', function() {
  if (($window.scrollTop() + $window.innerHeight()) == $document.height()) {
    footer.stop(true).animate({opacity: 1}, 250);
  } 
  else {
    footer.stop(true).animate({opacity: 0}, 250);
  }
});
</script>
```

Just fades in and out on the bottom of the page condition. I looked around and there seems to be several ways to go about doing this and I was wanting to know the most effective solution.

I thought I had found a jfiddle for a solution a while ago but can't seem to find that question anymore and it required me to dig quite a bit.

I'm not exactly sure all of the factors that go into mobile not being compatible with this solution I currently have, so it's hard for me to determine what needs adjusting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually figured out the issue is that it needs to be the exact document height if I'm using '==', in mobile devices the viewpoint doesn't trigger the script while moving or scrolling so I had t change the '==' to '>=' in my condition and then add height to my viewport.

```
if (($window.scrollTop() + $window.innerHeight()) >= $document.height())
```

And in my header viewport tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And it works perfectly!